# What tests should I run in SPSS?

Tags: spss

I'm running SPSS v. 23.

I have a dataset of 257 rows originating from ArcMap analysis. It contains the following variables/columns (all distances are in meters):

Nest location (string, names of 3 locations)

Nesting outcome (string; fail, success, unknown)

Number of chicks fledged (numeric; 0,1,2.3)

Distance to connected windfarms (numeric)

Distance to contracted windfarms (numeric)

And distances to 100s of other variables that I'm not interested in and the area (ha) of a number of habitat types surrounding the nest points.

The questions I'm asking are:

Are nests closer to connected or to contracted windfarms? Does this vary significantly with location?

Does nesting outcome vary with distance to windfarms? How? i.e. are nests most successful when the distance to windfarms is large or small?

Does number of chicks fledged vary with distance to windfarms?

I have tried Analyze > Correlate > Bivariate for Kendall's tau, Spearman and Pearson, but this does not take string variables.

I have also tried Analyze > Descriptive Stats > Crosstabs for Pearson Chi-square, Phi and Cramer's V, but not sure how applicable this is as for distances as each of the 257 will have a different distance so the crosstabs count table it produces is massive. Would breaking the distances into categories work here? e.g. three categories of 0-5km, 5-10km, >10km?

Compare means > One-way ANOVA with post-hoc Tukey works to see the differences between the 3 locations and distances to windfarms, but does not work for number of young fledged (likely because only 1 nest fledged 5 chicks). What would work for young fledged vs distance to windfarms?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to run a multivariate analysis of variance (MANOVA).

> Are nests closer to connected or to contracted windfarms? Does this vary significantly with location?

For this question, I believe you have 2 DVs (distance to connected/contracted windfarms), and 3 IVs (location, outcome, # of chicks). If this is correct, Analyze > General Linear Model > Multivariate.

See this pdf: http://health.uottawa.ca/biomech/courses/apa6101/How%20to%20perform%20a%20MANOVA%20in%20SPSS.pdf